# Error in Python when installing a package "yfinance"

Tags: python

This is the error message.

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Plus, I am looking for any source that could use the brand name to get the ticker of the company.

I tried the following:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools

pip install lxml

brew update && brew install python@3.11
```

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: @Volk - brew hints towards MacOS

Comment: Fro mac-OS: STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml according official site: https://lxml.de/installation.html

Comment: Thanks, Volk. Does this error message I have mean that my environment does not have "lxml" and I need to install it?